# Quickest way to compare two generic lists C#

Tags: c#, list, algorithm, performance, generic-list

I need to know what is the best way to compare two list, for example:

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "ITEM", "FROM", "TO", "X kg/cm2g", "Y kg/cm2g" };

var list2 = new List<string> { "ITEM", "TO", "FROM", "Y", "X" };
```

Then, my items in list 2 exist in list 1, in this case is correct because I need only know if items in list 1 contains list 2.

for example

`"ITEM"` exist

`"TO"` exist

`"FROM"` exist

`Y` exist because "**Y** kg/cm2g"

`X` exist because "**X** kg/cm2g"

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide code samples of what you've tried so far.

Comment: Please update your question with your best attempt at solving this yourself and explain why it doesn't meet your criteria for performance / speed.

Comment: And, where does the `generic` part come into your question; your examples would seem to use two `List<string>` (I'm assuming - I can't see your code)?  Also, please specify the rules more precisely.  For example, if List 1 contained `"Steve Young"`, and List 2 contained `"Y"`, would it count as a match?  What about if it was the other way around?

Comment: Are you really interested in the quickest way? or just a solution... If you are interested in the "quickest way" you need to explain how this is being used, how often the lists changes, and be comparing it against some way that you know is actually working... I.e Quickest compared to what? fingers and toes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to verify that all items in `list2` are contained within at least one item in `list1`. If that's the case, this should do the trick:

```
bool list1ContainsList2Items = list2.All(l2 => list1.Any(l1 => l1.Contains(l2)));
```

Comment: Could you explain why this is *the quickest* ?

Comment: @devlincarnate because it took less than a minute to write and it's faster than the op's current solution, which is nothing. :) If you want to spend time on an optimized solution for this question, please be my guest!

Answer (score 0):

you could concatenate items from list 1 to one big string and loop through it checking if it contains item from list 2.

Comment: since the OP is asking for "the quickest", can you comment on the time complexity for your solution?

Comment: With simple concatenation ( "LOUIS", "TAN" ) and ( "LOU", "IS", "STAN" ) produce interesting results. Do you plan to delimit the strings? How would you handle strings that contain the delimiter?